# How to wrap a selection of twitter bootstrap tabs as one form?

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap tabs componenet.

I want two of the tabs to be part of a form. and the third to not be.

So I thought, I'll just wrap the two tabs in a form.

But it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/gLrr4/1/

Basically whilst the classes get applied to the right elements, it seems that the form is stopping the respective tabs from changing their visibility.

How can I fix this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gLrr4/1/
Demo Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src='http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="alert alert-error">Tab 1 and two are wrapped in a form tag!</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class="span12">

        <div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">#tab1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">#tab2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">#tab3</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <form class="form-vertical">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                        <div class="alert alert-info">
                            This is #tab1
                        </div>
                        <div class='form-actions'>
                            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Save changes</button>
                            <button id='cancel' class='btn'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                        <div class="alert alert-info">
                            This is #tab2
                        </div>
                        <div class='form-actions'>
                            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Save changes</button>
                            <button id='cancel' class='btn'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        This is #tab3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want the third tab in the form?

Comment: Yeah, I am surprised this is not a supported use-case, I could see it being a common practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little bit of JavaScript:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    $(e.target.hash).closest('.tab-content')
        .find('> form > .tab-pane.active:not(' + e.target.hash + '), 
               > .tab-pane.active:not(' + e.target.hash + ')')
        .removeClass('active');
});
```

And a smidge of CSS:

```
.tab-content > form > .tab-pane,
.pill-content > form > .pill-pane {
    display: none;
}
.tab-content > form > .active,
.pill-content > form > .active {
    display: block;
}
```

we can now nest the tabs in a form. Of course, this only supports form tags, not any child.

I could make it support any element by removing the `>`s but the issue is that that would cascade down if we had nested tabs.

Answer (score 2):

There are a two issues that need "fixing" to get this to work.

##### First problem: The first two tabs are displayed at the same time.

**Cause**: bootstrap.css (not minified) lines 4042 and 4047 select only the immediate descendants of the div:

```
.tab-content > .tab-pane
```

and

```
.tab-content > .active
```

**Resolution**: Add the following CSS to a separate CSS file:

```
.tab-content .tab-pane
{
  display: none;
}

.tab-content .active
{
  display: block;
}
```

##### Second problem: The third tab is now always displayed once it's been clicked and another tab is selected.

**Cause**: This is because when Bootstrap clears the "active" class from the tabs that haven't been clicked, it only looks for direct descendants of the container. On line 1563 of bootstrap.js:

```
var $active = container.find('> .active')
```

**Resolution**: To fix this, you'll need to change this line to:

```
var $active = container.find('.active')
```

However, this is not ideal. So if you don't want to change the Bootstrap code you can:

- Copy all the bootstrap-tab stuff between lines 1510 and 1624
- Rename all occurrences of `Tab` to `NewTab`
- Change `$.fn.tab` from line 1602 to `$.fn.modifiedTab` or similar
- Change `(data = new Tab(this))` from line 1606 to `(data = new NewTab(this))`
- Use it as per [the documentation](https://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs), but `.tab` becomes `.modifiedTab`

Comment: Oh, thanks @greg84, looks like we both came up with the solution at the same time, but there is a reason that twitter uses the direct descendant modifier, because this will break nested tabs, check out my answer :)

Comment: That makes sense - who needs nested tabs anyway? ;)

Comment: Actually, although I didn't show it my third tab actually uses nested tabs!