# Is it valid to have form tags that start in one div and end in another?

Tags: html, forms, validation

Because of some JavaScript/CSS rules I have, I cannot just wrap these two `div`s in a form tag and be done with it.

So, I am wondering if the below HTML is considered valid?

```
<div id="tab1">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="whatever" />
</div>

<div id="tab2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: No. But more importantly, though, is the question: why would you even *want* to do this?

Comment: @DavidThomas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503966/how-to-wrap-a-selection-of-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-as-one-form

Comment: In tab1, have hidden inputs matching the inputs in tab2 (and vice-versa), have separate forms for each tab, event listen for (on)submit and fill in the hidden inputs.

Comment: @xception Looking at your answer, it has just one `<form>`, not two, you don't have matching/hidden `<inputs>` for each tab and you did a typo'd _click_ event, which is different to _submit_, it is different. I also commented rather than answered because it was in reply to the previous comments here, and not an answer to "is it valid?".

Comment: Related: [Can I start a HTML element in one jsp page, close it in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32918432/can-i-start-a-html-element-in-one-jsp-page-close-it-in-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not valid HTML/XML.

Even worse, it will be parsed as:

```
<div id="tab1">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="whatever" />
    </form> <!-- form will be closed here, because parent is being closed -->
</div>

<div id="tab2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form> <!--  not sure about what happens with this one, but it will be either removed or replaced with empty <form></form> element -->
</div>
```

Comment: What you say about the parsing is only partly true. The HTML parsing in a case like this is *really* weird. In fact, in the DOM created by the parser, the form element contains only the text input box. The submit button is a direct child of the tab2 div. *But* the close form tag is not simply discarded. It marks the end of the form, such that the submit button, since it precedes it, is nevertheless associated with the form. That means that clicking the button will submit the form with the "whatever" parameter supplied.

Answer (score 1):

Covered here: http://www.impressivewebs.com/dom-improperly-nested/

It is invalid XML/XHTML, but HTML5 will be more tolerant.  The display/strucutre may not be consistent so it should be tested thoroughly.  Many browsers now will automatically "correct" this type of format.  It is best avoided in any case.

Answer (score -2):

This is not valid syntax for *any* element tags in HTML. You can't have an element be the child of only part of an ancestor; elements must be wholly contained within a single direct parent/ancestor element.

The only scenario where this kind of partial-ancestor syntax would be acceptable is if you had generated code that were inserted at run-time, changing the markup to become valid before being presented to the end user.