# Can I start a HTML element in one jsp page, close it in another?

Tags: java, html, jsp, include

I want to know if I can put the start tag of a HTML element inside an "include" in jsp, and close the HTML element outside that include file, or even in another include file. For example, I have this website:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
            <mytags:scriptLoader />
            <mytags:cssLoader />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="bodycontainer" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9">
                    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/sidebar.jsp" />
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <h2>Welcome</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <hr />
            <footer>&copy; 2015 by ...</footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and I changed to

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" %>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/footer.jsp" %>
```

where header.jsp is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <mytags:scriptLoader />
        <mytags:cssLoader />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="bodycontainer" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9">
                <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/views/sidebar.jsp" />
```

and footer.jsp is:

```
        </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr />
        <footer>&copy; 2015 by ...</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

The thing is, Eclipse keep warning about the tags not being closed on header.jsp and tags without start on footer.jsp.

The website is working fine on my web browser for now, but I wonder if there are going to be any problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spill the code across JSPs by making sure it forms valid HTML  when they work together. But it is always suggested to define the layout in one jsp and sections in to other as required for better code management.