# How to use form tags that wraps 3 tabs of 5 in Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a twitter bootstrap tabs component where i have five tabs.I want 3 of the tabs to be part of a form and the 4th, 5th not be.

So I thought, I'll just wrap the 3 tabs in a form.But it does not work. I have already checked [How to wrap a selection of twitter bootstrap tabs as one form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503966/how-to-wrap-a-selection-of-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-as-one-form) this thread and from the first answer got two issues. Since in the 2nd answer issues are explained but i am expecting better solution using js and without modifying bootstrap core file.

I am using twitter bootstrap 3.3.2. How can I fix this?

Here is the sample code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 animated-panel zoomIn" style="animation-delay: 0.4s;">
        <div class="hpanel">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">Third</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab">Fourth</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#tab-5" data-toggle="tab">Fifth</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
            <form>
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-1">
                    <div class="panel-body">First tab fields
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">
                    <div class="panel-body">Second tab fiels
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-3">
                    <div class="panel-body">Third tab fields
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-4">
                    <div class="panel-body">Fourth tab content
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-5">
                    <div class="panel-body">Fifth tab content
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess since bootstraps javascript conflicts with this kind of form placing you need to build an (dirty) workaround if you really want to use bootstraps tabs with this kind of form-placing.

You could place inside each of the first three tabs an single form and copy (only for submitting) the content of the other forms into the form submitted.

@lonesomeday [mentions a way to intercept submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5169572/1402667)

So you could do something like

```
$(document).on('submit', '.tab-pane:lt(3) form', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.tab-pane:lt(3) form').not($(this)).children().clone().addClass('toRemove').hide().appendTo($(this));
   this.submit();
   $('.toRemove').remove();
});
```

***Note:*** I did not test the code above

If your submit-button/trigger is outside of the tab-structure you could just copy the contents of the three tabs into an hidden form anywhere on the page and submit this one.

**Another way** would be to invoke jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) without using forms.